# Find $x,y$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p\not \mid n$ ($p$ prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^2+y^2=n$

Tags: number-theory

How to show that there exist $x,y$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ where $p\not \mid n$ ($p$ prime and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^2+y^2\equiv n \mod p$.

Can someone give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write it $x^2 \equiv n - y^2$, and pigeon-hole it.

Comment: What means "pigeon-hole" it?

Comment: Apply the pigeon-hole principle to prove that a solution exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Brahmagupta Fibonacci identity the set $A$ of elements of the form $x^2+y^2$ different from zero are closed under multiplication, thus they form a subgroup of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_p$.

It is easy to see they have more than half of the elements, because if $S$ is the set of squares then $A$ contains $S$ and $S+1$, therefore $A$ is all of the multiplcative group of $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: Great answer, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the morphisms

$$\begin{array}{cccc}
f:&\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z&\longrightarrow &\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\\
 & x &\longmapsto & x^2
\end{array}$$

And, 
$$\begin{array}{cccc}
g:&\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z&\longrightarrow &\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\\
 & y &\longmapsto & n-y^2
\end{array}$$

So $Im(f)\cap Im(g)\neq \emptyset$ (this follows from $|Im(f)|=|Im(g)|=\frac{p-1}{2}+1$), therefore there exist $x,y$ such that $x^2=n-y^2$, as we wanted to see.